# Managing many clients with the same java projects with small changes

Tags: java, svn, jenkins, project-management

I have several java projects with small differences between them for each client, those differences are:

- differences in jrxml reports
- differences in properties files
- Changes in static classes

[image: Projects Differences]

When I go to update the clients, I committed to SVN and generating the WAR for each project (approx 90mb) using Jenkins, upload to FTP and install it on each server.

The problem I'm having is the time it takes me to do it this way, which is between 3 and 4 hours for 6 projects every week.

1. It is possible that all clients are handled by a single project (single WAR) and separate the differences outside the war?
2. What would be the best way to do this?
3. This is recommended or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible that all clients are handled by a single project (single WAR) and separate the differences outside the war?

Sure but... bear with me for a second.

With 4 hours of building/deployment time i'd say the bandwith between the jenkins server and you production servers could be the issue. If upgrading it is not viable you will need to optimize your projects setup.

Usually 90% of the size of a war file is composed by the collection of libraries your application relies on to do his job (spring, hibernate, struts and so on...).
Supposing you currently store them in your WEB-INF/lib folder, you could consider to extract those and install them in your application server shared classpath, removing them from your war.

It will not shock me if after this operation you will not need further optimizations...

Comment: i tried it (the WAR size change to 24mb), but struts2 libraries don't work very well when is another project using the same libraries with different properties. i will try to change all Struts2 and log4 properties to the same values and see if work fine

Comment: @aegis: Could you provide further information about that? Do all your projects are running on the same application server? Could you also confirm the bandwidth is the issue you are facing?

Comment: on some servers we have two different projects; a management system and a logistic system. those project shared the same libraries (Struts2, Spring AOP, Jasper) but have different configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I need to save time, this command saves me every time:

```
rsync -razpv --delete /folder/name server_name:/folder/name
```

you can also add:

```
--exclude 'file/inside/folder'
```

Use it cleanly, and wisely, but a process of copying files for some of my builds that took 20 minutes always, now take 10 seconds when there is no change, and less than 1 minute when there is a change.

Also - did you think about a management tool (puppet/chef/ansible) to do some of the work?